# Ubuntu Mate destroyed non-uefi boot sector

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, uefi

I tried to install Ubuntu Mate to replace an Xubuntu 64 bit installed aside to windows7. The result was that it did no more boot at all (black screen with some short message I don't remember).

By "chance" I had an Xubuntu 32 bit on an usb stick, installling it restored the boot sector. But now I am stuck with Ubuntu 32 bit (and Windows7).

I think it is because I have a non-UEFI Asus ul80vt and Ubuntu Mate considered it was uefi without asking any question, resulting in boot failure.

I would like to re-install a 64 bit version of Xubuntu or Mint or Debian, but I am afraid I will encounter the same problem. How to be sure installation of a distribution will take in account it is an non UEFI computer ?
Which distribution should I install to adress this issue ?

Comment: You control how the install media boots/installs by the UEFI settings.  It has both boot mechanisms, so will boot the one selected by your machine's settings.

Comment: I finally did reinstall an Xubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit distribution and there was no problem. I don't know why it gone wrong with the Mate distribution.